# How to modifie edge.TEA (networkDynamic) and use them as edge.lwd (render.d3movie)

Tags: r, networking

I have a problem: I want to create a dynamic network with edges that have a weight. This weight must also represent the size of the connection on a graph. My problem is that I can't get a dynamic attribute that changes with time and use it in my animations.

```
MoE <- network.initialize(2)
add.edges.active(MoE,tail=1,head=2,onset=0, terminus=4)
activate.edge.attribute(MoE,'weight',1,onset=0,terminus=1,e=1) 
activate.edge.attribute(MoE,'weight',2,onset=1,terminus=2,e=1) 
activate.edge.attribute(MoE,'weight',3,onset=2,terminus=Inf,e=1)
render.d3movie(MoE, edge.lwd = (MoE %e% "weight"))
```

If I put weight.active and not weight for edge.lwd it doesn't change anything. I tried also to manually change the network :

```
MoE <- network.initialize(2)
add.edges.active(MoE,tail=1,head=2,onset=0, terminus=4)
activate.edge.attribute(MoE,'weight',1,onset=0,terminus=0,e=1) 
MoE$mel[[1]]$atl$weight.active[[1]] <- list(1,2,3)
MoE$mel[[1]]$atl$weight.active[[2]] <- matrix(c(0,1,2,1,2,Inf),ncol=2)
render.d3movie(MoE, edge.lwd = (MoE %e% "weight"))
```

But that doesn't help. Could you help me to understand how I could modify an attribute over time for my edges and use this attribute to make graphics in particular! Many thanks

SOLUTION /!\

> render.d3movie(net, usearrows = F, displaylabels = F,
> edge.lwd =  function(slice)(slice %e% "w"))

Comment: The solution is to use slice, 

render.d3movie(net, usearrows = F, displaylabels = F, 
               edge.lwd =  function(slice)(slice %e% "w"))